# Calculate MinDate and MaxDate based on table relationship

Tags: sql

Following is the condition to write a create a query has per the requirement.

Visit 1 Date for the Patient(Abc) should be calculated fom the "Screening" visit of the patient.

For example if the Patient (Abc) has visited on 23/Mar/2019 then  with  Min Date (22/Mar/2019) and MaxDate (25/Mar/2019).

In the VisitWindow I am linking the VisitWindowId to VisitId in the table for VisitEntry.

So if you see the visitWindowId  you can see that I have mention MinDays (1) and MaxDays(2) which is to be calculated using the VisitDate for the   VisitName is equal to "Screening".

For example I expecting the query or write the query to give the below result.

I struck with writing the desired query to get the result

Table - VisitEntry

```
--------------------
RecordId    VisitId     VisitName   VisitDate   PatientId   PatientName
1           1          Screening    23/Mar/2019      100        Abc
2           2          Visit 1 Date 23/Mar/2019      100        Abc
```

Table - VisitWindow

```
-------------------
RecordId    VisitId     VisitWindowId   MinDays     MaxDays
1            2           1               1           2
```

Expected QueryResult

```
--------------------
RecordId    VisitId     VisitName      VisitDate    PatientId   MinDate     MaxDate
1              1        Screening      23/Mar/2019     100      NUll        Null
2              2        Visit 1 Date   23/Mar/2019     100      22/Mar/2019 25/Mar/2019
```

Comment: Will there be only 1 Screening records ber Patient? Will there be only One Visit per patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the db, so I'll give you 2.

SQL Server:

```
SELECT ve.RecordID, ve.VisitID, ve.VisitName, ve.VisitDate, ve.PatientID, ve.PatientName,
dateadd(d, sd.VisitDate, -1 * vw.MinDays) MinDate,
dateadd(d, sd.VisitDate, vw.MaxDays) MaxDate
FROM VisitEntry ve
LEFT JOIN VisitEntry sd ON (ve.PatientId=sd.PatientId AND sd.VisitName='Screening')
LEFT JOIN VisitWindow vw ON ve.VisitID=vw.VisitID
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT ve.RecordID, ve.VisitID, ve.VisitName, ve.VisitDate, ve.PatientID, ve.PatientName,
sd.VisitDate - vw.MinDays MinDate,
sd.VisitDate + vw.MaxDays MaxDate
FROM VisitEntry ve
LEFT JOIN VisitEntry sd ON (ve.PatientId=sd.PatientId AND sd.VisitName='Screening')
LEFT JOIN VisitWindow vw ON ve.VisitID=vw.VisitID
```

Comment: this is incorrect query. for the first row  mindate and max date would be null. for second row it should pick the visitdate of VisitName which is eqauls to "Screening" and then it should calculate the mindate and maxdate. Please check the relationship set in  VisitWindowId column

Comment: i think i understand.  you want the second row to be plus/minus the date of the Screening.  i adjusted the query to do this.  but it is not clear how the visit date relates to the screening date.  currently i linked on the patient id.  but this will not work if the same patient has multiple screenings.  if this is the case then you could do some more advanced filtering on the subquery.  take a look at the new version to see if i'm going in the right direction, and hopefully you can tweak it from here.